# Does a graph with at least $2^t$ maximal cliques contain the octahedral graph $O_t$ as a vertex-induced subgraph?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

For a positive integer $t$, define the *octahedral graph* $O_t$ as follows:

Let $tK_2 =(V,E)$ for $V=\{1,2,\dots,2t\}$ and $E=\{ [i, i+t] \mid 1 \leq i \leq t \}$, i.e., $tK_2$ consists of $t$ pairwise disjoint edges. Then $O_t$ is defined to be the graph complement of $tK_2$.

In a [recent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.06301.pdf) of Yamaji we see the following "Folklore" theorem:

> **Theorem 1.3 (Folklore).** *If a graph contains $O_t$ as a vertex-induced subgraph, then its number of maximal cliques is lower-bounded by $2^t$.*

**Question.** I can believe this statement, however, is its *converse* also true? That is, if a graph has at least $2^t$ maximal cliques, can we always find $O_t$ as an induced subgraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse only holds for $t=1$. We first show it holds for $t=1$. Observe that $O_1$ consists of two isolated vertices. The only graphs with one maximal clique are cliques, so if $G$ has two maximal cliques, $G$ has a pair of non-adjacent vertices, i.e., an induced $O_1$.

Now let $t>1$, and consider the graph $G$ composed of $2^t$ isolated vertices. Observe that $O_t$ is not an induced subgraph of $G$, as $G$ has no edges. In fact, this shows that there is no function $f(t)$ such that having $f(t)$ maximal cliques implies containment of an induced $O_t$. This counterexample also works if you replace the isolated vertices by cliques (of any size), since any induced subgraph of a collection of disjoint cliques is a collection of disjoint cliques, and $O_t$ is not, as, for instance, $O_t$ contains an induced $P_3$.

---

**EDIT:** Adding additional connectivity conditions is not enough for $G$ to contain $O_t$. Observe that by construction, $O_t$ is $(2t-2)$-connected, meaning $O_t$ is connected when deleting any set of at most $2t-3$ vertices. We can modify our previous example by taking $f(t)$ many cliques on at least $2t-2$ vertices. Index these cliques by $[f(t)]$, and add a matching between consecutive cliques of size $2t-3$ (this increases the number of maximal cliques of $G$ to $(2t-3)(f(t)-1)+f(t)$, but it doesn't really matter). Then $G$ is $(2t-3)$-connected but not $(2t-2)$-connected, since deleting one side of a matching, $2t-3$ vertices, disconnects $G$. Any $(2t-2)$-connected induced subgraph of $G$ is contained in one of the cliques, but as before, cliques only contain cliques as induced subgraphs, so $G$ does not contain $O_t$ as an induced subgraph.

Now what if we require $G$ to be $(2t-2)$-connected? This is still not enough. First, consider $t>2$. Again, take $f(t)$ cliques of size exactly $2t-2$ (I think larger also works, but it is more tedious of an analysis), and now add a matching of size $2t-2$ to consecutive cliques. Let us call the cliques of size $2t-2$ *big*. $G$ is now $(2t-2)$ connected. Note that $O_t$ is obtained from $K_{2t}$ by deleting a matching of size $t$. Every vertex in $O_t$ has degree $2t-2$. Suppose for contradiction $H$ is an induced copy of $O_t$ in $G$. Then $H$ is contained in at least two big cliques, and all big cliques intersecting $H$ are consecutive, since $H$ is connected. If $H$ is contained in exactly two big cliques, say $K^1$ and $K^2$, then $|V(K^1)\cap V(H)| = |V(K^2)\cap V(H)| = t$, since $O_t$ does not contain a clique of size $t+1$. But there are only $t$ edges joining $K^1$ to $K^2$, and the cliques in $O_t$ of size $t$ are joined by $t(t-1)$ edges. This is a contradiction since $t>2$. Suppose now that $H$ intersects $G$ in at least three big cliques. $H$ must then intersect $G$ in exactly three big cliques, as $H$ has no induced $P_4$. Consider these three consecutive cliques, $K^1, K^2, K^3$. We have $|V(K^i)\cap V(H)|\geq 2$ for $i\in \{1,3\}$, since if one of these big cliques intersect $H$ in exactly one vertex, $H$ has a degree one vertex, and every vertex in $H$ has degree $2t-2\geq 2$. Observe that any induced subgraph of $O_t$ of size four contains at least four edges, but taking the subgraph formed from two vertices in $K^1$ and two vertices in $K^3$, we obtain a subgraph with only two edges, a contradiction.

Finally, to tackle the $t=2$ case, we want a $2t-2=2$-connected graph $G$ with no induced $O_2\cong C_4$. Consider the cycle on $f$ vertices, $C_f$, where $f\geq 5$. $C_f$ has $f$ maximal cliques (every edge forms a maximal clique), but it does not contain $C_4$ as an induced subgraph.

The above arguments show that the converse of the folklore theorem is very far from true, in the sense that it is not true even when adding additional connectivity as an assumption. To make it true, I think you could potentially add some restriction on the size of $G$. At a high level, the big cliques do a lot of heavy lifting for us.

Comment: Thanks. What if we assume the graph is connected?

Comment: I've added a discussion about requiring extra connectivity. Long story short: the converse still doesn't hold. @pyridoxal_trigeminus

Comment: Thanks. I think I was imagining that the number of vertices is something like $O(t)$, but I'll leave that for another possible future question.